# A quick clarification about elementary row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was solving a homework question that asks me why 3R2 - 2R1 is not an elementary row operation. Is it because we are doing subtraction instead of addition? However, I feel like that it not it. I mean 3R2 + -2R1 is the same thing. I'm adding now and multiplying R1 by negative 2.

Comment: Is there a specific matrix to which that applies?

Comment: Wouldn't R2-2R1 be an elementary row operation? The problem, I think, would be that R2 is multiplied by a number as well as R1. At least, that's what I gather from the list here http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/elemop/elemop.html

Answer (score 3):

There are three types of elementary row operations.

1. Swap two rows
2. Multiply a row by a non-zero constant
3. Add a multiple of one row to another row

You are trying to do the two elementary row operations at once: multiply row $1$ by $-2$ (item 2) and add $3$ lots of row $2$ to row $1$ (item 3).

Comment: ohhhh, so you can only do one at a time. Does this also apply to Gaussian elimination?

Comment: I see that Wikipedia agrees with you that 2. is an elementary row operation. But many people think it isn't because it changes the value of the determinant (assuming the determinant is non-zero).

Comment: @Ayoshna Yes, because Gaussian elimination uses row operations. Generally, I find my students make less mistakes when they do one row operation at a time than combining two at once.

Comment: @almagest Swapping rows also changes the value of the determinant (makes it negative), which would make the first two fall under this criterion(?). As it is known how the value of the determinant changes under these three elementary row operations, I don't see how this would make the second non-elementary.

Comment: Adding a multiple of one row to another row doesn't change the value of the determinant.

Comment: @almagest I didn't say the third item did change the determinant. In a technical sense, it scales by a factor of $1$, which results in no change to the value of the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

I will agree that your operation is a combination of two elementary row operations and that is why it is non-elementary but I will note that every invertible matrix can be expressed as the product of elementary row operations and I feel that it would defeat the point if every invertible matrix was considered elementary.

This is more of an explanation why the combination of elementary row operations is not considered elementary.